# Resizeable tableView cell with tableView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a tableView with custom cells in which each cell can have different types of views ranging from key-value pair labels, map, buttons , list and more depending upon the data coming from the server and those views will be populated accordingly. I have created custom XIB for each view type which i will be using

So for this I took a parentTableView whose cell will have a childTableView whose each cell will be the different type of view depending on the data from the server

[image]

NOTE - Call and Navigation button and Assigned label are not cells but are added on top of the cell

Now I have two questions :

1. How can i make the childTableView to disable scrolling feature and take the full height of its content (In the image after last `assignedTo`, there is a `priority` field which is currently clipped as i have defined the height of the tableView cell to be 200 )
2. Dynamic height for parentTableView's cell (which is almost similar to first question)

I tried setting `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` for `parentTableView` but it is collapsing the cells

```
parentTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
parentTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300.0
```

[image]

Comment: Better if you use single tableView with feature section and row.

Comment: Try to use single table view with strategy pattern, take a look at : 

https://github.com/sergiog90/Strategy-Pattern-iOS/tree/master/swift/swift-strategy-pattern

Comment: @Setar In your case i believe you can have either one of those 3 view type for a cell but i my case i can have a combination of them all in a single cell which will be separated by sections for the childTableView

Comment: i don't understand why the cells in the parent can't be the section header view and the childTableView can't be simple row cells. 
you can apply strateggy patern in header view also if you need.
If you want a tableView inside another, and only use the upper tableview scroll you will have to specity the inner tableview height setting num rows * row height. or having two scrolls but i think it's not a good achievement

Comment: @Setar Can you please explain the approach that you defined above _why the cells in the parent can't be the section header view_? I have _Job Card_ which has a _Assigned_ label as you can see . Now you want me to create that _Job Card_ as sectionView (Header Section for tableView) for that tableView . Okay. Then where will I put the different cells that will come inside the same _Job Card_(like label pair, button pair or map)? Because the rows will follow **after** the section header but I want them inside the card(Which I have now made the section Header View). Can you please help me out !

Comment: @dahiya_boy can you explain that approach a bit ?

Comment: @Setar I have different types of cell(`childTableView`'s cell) inside the card(`parentTableView`'s cell)

Comment: @Setar I have somewhat figured this thing but I am stuck at [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58410746/nested-tableview-causing-childtableviews-content-getting-clipped)

Comment: @user121095 i'm not sure if im understanding your needs, and probably there's a better  approach than using nested tableViews. but maybe what you need is to force reload only the cell heights you can do this by calling             tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()

Answer (score 0):

remove `parentTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

and update your cell height to calculated `cell.tableView.contentSize.height`

ref:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
     return cell.tableView.contentSize.height
}`

Comment: You're referring to the tableView from inside the cell ? Is that a right approach ?

Comment: And moreover `heightForRowAt` of the parentTableView will be called before the childTableView is actually created

Comment: you should create childTableView in your table view cell custom class.