# Nested tableView causing childTableView's content getting clipped

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am working with nested tableViews having a `parentTableView` and `childTableView` .

`parentTableView` has the cards and `childTableView` will have the data which will be available at runtime so I have used resizable cells

Now my problem is when I initially load the tableviews, the `childTableView` data is getting clipped

[image]

But when i reload the `parentTableView` (I have managed a logic for that) using `reloadData()`, the data is displaying correctly

[image]

I have subclassed my `childTableView` like --

```
class SectionsTableView: UITableView {

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
      self.layoutIfNeeded()
      return self.contentSize
  }

  override var contentSize: CGSize {
      didSet{
          self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
      }
  }

  override func reloadData() {
      super.reloadData()
      self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
  }

}
```

This `reloadData()` is a workaround but it creates issues in other part of my code which I have to explicitly deal with. Has anyone experienced the same ?

Comment: so basically you are putting a whole new table view into a tableview cell ?

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary Yes. The requirement is as such : My requirement is like such : I have a Job card which will be reusable ( as in it will always be the same cell that will get repeated) . I have taken a parentTableView for that. Now the data inside the Job card can be of various types , say , key-value pair label , combination of buttons or a map or more in the future . Now there be one or more types of these views like 3 key-value pair labels , 1 map . There is no guarantee that all of them will be present . This will be decided on runtime as per the data .

Comment: ... To handle interactions that which key-value pair was selected, I have taken it inside another tableView. These all different kind of views will be combined inside one Single Job Card . Now this Job Card will be same for all the cells inside the parentTableView (only the data like customerName and other data will change in each card) . Can i achieve the same with section approach ?

Comment: got it, are you sure you are providing correct cell height of the cell in which you are putting your "child" table ? if yes the child table should not clip else it may clip or wont properly load data or might affect scrolling.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary I am using Auto-Resizing cells

Comment: I am not sure if it will work in such case, table views are not designed like that because it reuses its cells, you have to provide exact height of child table as cell's height or it may show above behaviour. keep the cell in which you are adding new table as completely different cell, should not be reused. and you may use auto size for remaining cell but not for this cell.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary But If i don't reuse the cell, and create a new cell for each row, wouldn't that degrade the performance if i get a lot of cells ?

Comment: Sections are good choice and may be an easy solution. I don't know exactly what data you are getting and how you are showing but personally I would be doing such case with multiple sections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200951/discussion-between-harvant-s-choudhary-and-user121095).